# why css animation run before jquery scroll

Tags: jquery, css, animation, keyframe

why css in html run before jquery? so when i scroll my page, animation flipInX didn't run, but when i refresh my page on the hexa element it's run so well,

so, i think that is run very well but its only before jquery

is there anyone know what should i do?

```
<div class="col-sm-3 hexa-col flipInX" data-animation="flipInX" data-delay=".2s" style="animation-delay: 0.2s;">
<div class="col-sm-3 hexa-col flipInX" data-animation="flipInX" data-delay=".2s" style="animation-delay: 0.4s;">



    @keyframes flipInX {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0; }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(-20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(-20deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg);
    opacity: 1; }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(5deg); }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px);
    opacity: 1; } }
```

Jquery code

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
31
    if (wScroll > $('.about').offset().top -100) {
        $('.about').each(function(i){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.about .disappearleft').eq(i).addClass('appearleft');
                $('.about .hexa').eq(i).addClass('appear');

            }, 300*(i+1));
        }); 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS will be applied as soon as it finds its elements in the DOM regardless of what your JS is doing.

You could use jQuery to programmatically add the flipInX class to your element whenever you want. Looks like you are already doing this on your .about elements.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wScroll > $('.hexa-col').offset().top -100) {
       $(".hexa-col").attr("data-animation", "flipInX");
    }
});
```

Comment: your code doesn't work idk why , so i decided to make several flipInX class with jquery.

in my code, i just wanna add flipInX  class in several div that have same class name